# Realm - List of possible error codes

Tags: javascript, realm, realm-object-server

In Realm Object Server sample codes, following can be found:

```
throw new deps.problem.HttpProblem.Unauthorized({
            detail: `Something bad happened: ${err.toString()}`,
          });
```

Here, like `deps.problem.HttpProblem.Unauthorized` there may be other defined errors that can be used. However, I could no where find such list or details in any docs or references.

Can anyone help me in here to get such list or errors?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/objectServer/java/io/realm/ErrorCode.java

Comment: Yes, that is what I had found too.. However, there seems to be official documentation for the same..